# Custom size UIModalPresentationPopover on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popover

I'm trying to add a `Popover` to my custom keyboard to show alternative emoji's when long pressing on a button, but I can't seem to get the Popover to be a custom size and it seems to appear as a Modal View filling the parent view...

I have my UIViewController initialised as such:

```
self.popoverViewController = [[PopoverDetailViewController alloc] init];
self.popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 50);
```

and then I handle the long press as such:

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
        self.popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [self.popoverViewController popoverPresentationController];
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
        presentationController.sourceView = self.view;
        presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(30, 50, 10, 10);

        [self presentViewController:self.popoverViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want a the `Popover` to appear from the button that was long pressed and have a custom size...
Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: That's the way it works.  Unfortunately, the best option seems to be WYPopover.  I say "unfortunate" because it's buggy and not very-well written.

Comment: @Avi Yeah, I was hoping I could avoid that :( I'm having some issues getting that to work in an App Extension

Answer (score 2):

Would need more information but this might be a result of adaptive presentation style. By default, at least on iPhone, the popover seems to appear full screen.

Here's some code below and [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/presentation-controllers-tutorial/) might help too.

`self.popoverPresentationController.delegate = yourDelegate;`

```
(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```